# circle-progress limitar el max Percent

Tags: angular, ionic

Teniendo

```
<circle-progress
  [percent]="valueProgress"
  [toFixed]="2"
  [maxPercent]="maxValue">
```

he definido que el maxValue sea igual a 10, pero al mostrar el circle-progress siempre toma el 100% en el maxPercent. Como puedo limitarlo a 10?

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve, al final lo hice asi:

```
          <circle-progress
          [percent]="(9.34 / 10) * 100"
          [toFixed]="2"
          [maxPercent]="100"
          [titleColor]="'#FFFFFF'"
          [title]="Titulo principal"
          [subtitle]="subtitulo"
          [space]="-10"
          [radius]="82"
          [outerStrokeWidth]="10"
          [innerStrokeWidth]="10"
          [animation]="true"
          [animationDuration]="300"
          [showTitle]=true
          [showUnits]=false>
        </circle-progress>
```

Con el showUnits ocultamos el '%'
documentación: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress